# QBO, QBD, API and app authorization

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

It drives me crazy, please help.

I want to integrate QuickBooks Enterprise 2014 with my website.

- I managed to create app via developer center.
- I managed to sync data using Sync Manager.
- I managed to see synced data i my appcenter account (company file).
- I managed to implement OAuth authorization with QuickBooks connect button
- I managed to use api explorer V3QBD (even though they say it's deprecated) to access synced data

now...

there is no option to choose desktop company file when authorizing... there is only a message saying I need QuickBooks Online subscription.

I don't want to subscribe to QBO, I want to access a company file synced via SyncManager.

Is it still possible ?

I read that you need to set your app to use desktop data source, but this option is not available anymore?

After one week of investigation I couldn't find answers to that, but one "you need to use web connector", is this true ?

please, confirm

thanks ahead

Comment: i'm getting tired with intuit's docs. Are they not updated ? what a mess...

Comment: I found [blog entry](https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/19/2014-roadmap-and-migration-dates-for-existing-developers) showing a table of options I have. Am I falling into 4th column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have been grandfathered in, you can not use sync manager and access QBD data through the API's. You will need to use the QBXML SDK and web connector for accessing desktop data.